# Xcode error - The executable was signed with invalid entitlements

Tags: ios, xcode, phonegap

I can build a game that I am developing in Objective-C no problem, and I can test run it when I hook my iPhone onto the macbook. But when I try to test an angular phonegap app through Xcode, I get the error:

```
The executable was signed with invalid entitlements.

The entitlements specified in your application’s Code Signing Entitlements file are invalid, not permitted, or do not match those specified in your provisioning profile. (0xE8008016).
```

I tried some settings, but it looks to me like the settings forsigning are the same as for the objective-c game. What's the catch?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an answer I was wondering if you ever found the solution to your problem.  Since I can't leave a comment on your question.  I'm entering it here.

Comment: No, I still haven't found it. I am with Apple on this, and they are being dodgy - I created an issue and they are dodging the problem for some reason....